# How would recent GBP exchange rate fall effect $ efforts to buy foreign-owned UK assets?

Tags: foreign-exchange, currency, corporate-acquisition, foreign

US-GBP exchange rate has been at its lowest since the mid-80s. That presumably means it's been cheaper to buy UK assets with dollars.

Let's say I have dollars and I want to acquire a UK company. Let's say the UK company does its accounts in GBP, but is 2/3-owned by a foreign investor. Let's assume the owner is looking to sell. Let's assume that the owner can insist on whatever currency it wants to make the sale, and whatever price. And lets consider this notwithstanding the fact that the company might have greater or lesser inherent value, the owner might have greater or lesser need to sell, and there might be many or few others wanting to buy it.

How might the recent fall in the exchange rate reasonably be expected to effect the price I might have to pay to acquire the firm?

Comment: Didn't you already ask this in a slightly different form? You will end up paying whatever price you agree with that party and no one here can predict what that will be.

Comment: I asked a different question that was closely related, yes. The answers to that one helped my understand enough to pose another question. Indeed, they helped me get closer to my ultimate question.